# I accidentally sent tokens to a wallet address on BSC which is a token contract address on Optimism but not on BSC. Can I get my tokens back?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, etherscan, smart-contract-wallets, binance-smart-chain

This is the link for token contract address on Optimism.
https://optimistic.etherscan.io/address/0x8700daec35af8ff88c16bdf0418774cb3d7599b4#code

This is the link for the address on BSC.
https://bscscan.com/address/0x8700daec35af8ff88c16bdf0418774cb3d7599b4

I accidentally sent my tokens to the BSC address. Can I get it back?

Comment: sadly not. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but the short answer is not possible.